# LibreOffice Writer ODT incorrectly putting black border on all frames

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I have a document that I saved with frames. Before saving there was no black border. Upon saving, and reopening, there appears 1 pixel black border on all frames.

Changing the default style doesn't remove the border, but overriding the individual frames style to have no border does.

[image]

File is saved as ODT.

I have a lot of frames. How do I remove all the black borders for all the frames at once? It is very tedious to do this to all the frames, and I'm afraid they may reappear again. The file was originally imported from DocX and that may be related.

Comment: I ended up solving it by manually changing each frame. Took awhile.

Answer (score 1):

See the [LibreOfffice page](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/202147/writer-how-can-i-find-text-by-attribute-and-replace-with-a-style/) on how to search and replace paragraph *styles* such as borders. The [Alternative Find & Replace for Writer](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/alternative-dialog-find-replace-for-writer) extension may also be helpful.

However, you may have changed the default document template to include borders. To edit a template:

- From the main menu, select `File` | `Templates` > `Manage Templates`.
- The template with a green check mark, ☑, is the default template. Select it.
- In the `Style and Formatting` box, select `Frame Styles`, the third item.
- Right click on `Frame` and select `Modify`.
- After editing the border settings, select `File` | `Templates` > `Save as Template...`
- Either use the original name, overwriting the old template, or pick a new name. Select `Set as Default`.

Your new documents, and old ones which are being updated on opening, should no longer have borders. However, if you've opened and then saved a document with the previous template, it may still have borders.